# Message filter headerless warning with custom message type

Tags: ros, custom-message, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I generated my custom message as following:

```
uint32 num_object
nav_msgs/Odometry custom
```

This is a part of the output when echoing a topic using my custom message:

```
---
num_object: 1
custom:
    header:
        seq: 0
        stamp:
            secs: 1636331652
            nsecs: 425379753
        frame_id: "base_footprint"
     child_frame_id: 'base_link'
    pose:
        pose:
          position:
.......
```

Here, the only part I'm not updating is a seq value. I provide the stamps using **rospy.Time.now()**

I'm using **ApproximateTimeSynchronizer**  to synchronize the custom message with another nav_msgs/Odometry message which has a header information:

```
pose_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/something', Pose)
odom_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([pose_sub, odom_sub], 5, 0.2)
ts.registerCallback(self._callback)
```

When I run the code, it shows a following warning:

```
[WARN] [1636331628.465729]: Cannot use message filters with non-stamped messages. Use the 'allow_headerless' constructor option to auto-assign ROS time to headerless messages.
```

I'm not sure what is causing this issue even if I provided most data in the header. Does seq value also matter when using the ApproximateTimeSynchronizer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390297/message-filter-headerless-warning-with-custom-message-type/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I generated my custom message as following:
>
> ```
> uint32 num_object
> ```

```
nav_msgs/Odometry custom
```

> I'm not sure what is causing this issue even if I provided most data in the header.

The `header` field needs to be in the root of the message.

The fact that your `custom` field is of type `nav_msgs/Odometry` and has a `header` field does not help here. The `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` will not look for a `std_msgs/Header` somewhere as a child of a child (ie: it won't see `custom.header`).

> Does seq value also matter when using the ApproximateTimeSynchronizer?

No, it doesn't.

As the name implies, the `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` considers only *time*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on 2021-11-08**:
That makes sense. I should probably reorganize my message.